# How to combine independent probabilities on parts of a series to get conditional probability over the entire series?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given a series $X_{0-2}$ if I have independent probabilities at each step for the series having a particular value say [$p_0$, $p_1$, $p_2$], how can I calculate the total probability $P_{0-2}$ of the entire series having a certain value?

Here are 2 possible analogies:

1. [Time series prediction] Given independent probability of weather prediction for each day of a week, how can I get the weather prediction for the entire week as a single prediction?
2. [Image classification] Looking at an image in 4 parts, if I assign each part a probability of belonging to a class, how can I combine those independent probabilities to get probability of the entire image belonging to a certain class?

Comment: You can't compute this purely from the marginals, unless you have an independence assumption. The best this can give you is the pseudolikelihood.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy: I feel out of my depth here, but assuming you are talking about independence between steps then that is indeed assumed, and any particular time step is *not* independent from the entire series. Do you have any resources I can follow up on marginals and pseudolikelihood that would be relevant to the question?